# How to reformat naming styles with ReSharper?

Tags: visual-studio, refactoring, resharper

I have several pages of code that need to have naming styles reinforced, e.g. use `fooBar` instead of `FooBar` for local variables. I don't want to correct it one by one for an obvious reason.

I tried to fiddle with the code cleanup profiles accessiable via `ReSharper > Tools > Cleanup Code > Edit Profiles`. I am not able to find a way to correct all naming style in one hit, or even with a keyboard shortcut. Could seasonsed ReSharper users advise how I can tackle this problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't believe ReSharper has a way to do a bulk rename like you want.  Changing the C# Naming Styles will certainly highlight (as warnings) those local variables that need changing, but Code Cleanup won't correct them for you.

There are times when renaming a variable to match a convention might result in one symbol colliding with another symbol that already exists; I imagine that's why ReSharper doesn't allow the bulk rename.

Two ReSharper shortcuts may make this pretty quick (and this is assuming you have adopted ReSharper's [shortcut keys for Visual Studio](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/docs/ReSharper50DefaultKeymap_VS_scheme.pdf)):

1. **Alt + PgDn** - Go to next highlight (error, warning or suggestion).  This will let you get from one misnamed variable to the next quite quickly.
2. **Alt + Enter** - Open the "Quick Fix" menu and select "Rename...".  This will rename the variable and update all references.

Comment: It seems to be impossible so far. I think you're the right point and my answer was deleted.

Comment: I have tried to write a macro to just pump R# to do this, but there's no good (non-awful screen-scraping SendKeys) way to detect when it finds conflicts, so it always only works until the first conflict. Personally, I've resigned myself to just biting the bullet on bulk jobs like these. Doing it manually actually takes you on a full tour of the code, which is extremely useful to get a better idea of other issues (than naming) you'll encounter.

Answer (score 8):

Starting from R# 8, there's the option to fix an issue in scope.

1. Go to any occurrence of this issue
2. Put the cursor on it
3. Show potential fixes (CTRL+.)
4. Select the first option 'Rename to xxx' and select 'fix naming in solution'

[More info](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/help/Code_Analysis__Fix_in_Scope.html)

Comment: Thank you so much, this is so useful

Comment: This is the only way I found that can do a Bulk Refactoring of variable names. Thanks so much for the Timesaving tip.

Answer (score 0):

R# has an SDK. Perhaps you can add a cleanup option via this:

http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/NETCOM/2.07+Code+Cleanup+%28R8%29

(I'm doing a mass naming refactor as well, but have only just started looking into writing something in their API. Don't know if this will work yet, or the effort involved.)

Answer (score 0):

Its included in resharper 2018, find an occurence of the incorrectly named variable, use the resharper context menu to fix all occurrence in the solution.