# Resharper Rename Fields

Tags: c#, .net, refactoring, resharper

I've been tasked with making some significant modifications to a legacy codebase that was not written using our current code style conventions.  The changes are extensive enough that I'm doing some cleanup and refactoring (there was quite a bit of dead code) before getting started.  One of the things that's bugging me is that the fields are following the m_FieldName naming convention whereas we now use _fieldName.

Is there some way with Resharper to automatically rename all fields in the project to follow the new convention?  Are there other tools that can readily do this?  It's not too difficult to remove the prefixing 'm' with even a simple search/replace, but I haven't found an automated way to change the case of the starting letter.

Comment: I use resharper, and can tell you it isn't capable of this (not automated anyway). See similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6433654/how-to-reformat-naming-styles-with-resharper

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It might be better to just find/replace `<m_` by `_` using Visual Studio (regular expression search/replace).

The `<` stands for "beginning of word".

Edit: There seems to be no way, using Find/Replace, to modify the casing of that first letter after the underscore.

So you would have to do this operation 26 times in a row, like so:

```
Replace <m_A by _a
Replace <m_B by _b
```

and then you're all set. Fun, too :-)  But it should only take a few minutes.

Comment: Very nice; 26 manual replaces is much easier than several hundred.

Comment: Worked beautifully; replaced about 4000 matches and everything still builds

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be available now in Resharper (I have v10):

[image]